# how can solve this problem with dynamic programming?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

[image]

**Instructions** : rat can move just up or right

**input**:

- The first line contains the number of table size n and the number of cheese m.
- From the next line, the position x, y of the cheese is given

**Output :**

- The maximum number of cheese to eat

**Exemple1:**

- input : `1 1 1`
- output : `1 1`

**Example2:**

- input :

```py
3 2
1 2
3 1
```

- output : `1`

**Example 3:**

- input :

```py
5 5
2 3
3 2
4 3
4 5
5 2
```

- output: `3`

how can I solve with python?
I tried

```
def maxAverageOfPath(table, N): 
    dp = [[0 for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)] 
    dp[0][0] = table[0][0] 
    # Initialize first column of total table(dp) array 
    for i in range(0, N): 
        dp[i][0] = 0


    for j in range(0, N): 
        dp[0][j] = 0

    for i in range(0, N): 
        for j in range(0, N):
            print(i, j)
            if i == N-1 and j == N-1:
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i - 1][j], dp[i][j - 1])
                continue
            if i == N-1 :
                dp[i][j] = table[i][j + 1]
                continue

            if j == N-1 :
                dp[i][j] = table[i + 1][j]
                continue
            dp[i][j] = max(table[i + 1][j], table[i][j + 1])

    return dp
```

but failed...

Comment: Hi. As it currently stands, your question is rather hard to understand for me. This is partly due to formatting (try to format the input/output fields and values better) and partly because of the problem description itself. What is the program supposed to do? What are the constraints? Lastly, try to comment your code to help people that will be trying to help you to understand it quicker. It will also help them to see where you made the wrong assumptions about what the code does/should do.

Comment: use bfs or dfs for your problem, starting from the intial poit , check the left and right, if chesse present store that point in that node, and again follow process til you reach the top row or exceed the boundry codidition,  and the get the total no of the cheese in each bfs branchc , max one will be the answer

Comment: In dynamic programming you should traverse the solutions from end to beginning, not from beginning to end, like you are doing now. That way, you always have all required information available.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele, there are both approaches good in DP. It's upon you whether you use Top-down or Bottom-up approach. Sometimes it's a problem specific as well. Here Bottom-up approach looks suitable as per problem statement.

Comment: @DevkinandanChauhan that's true, but then you need to remember to memoize the subresults. I think bottom-up is easier to grasp because you get memoization "for free" from the iteration order.

Comment: Try to use if, else if, else, rather than continues

Answer (score 3):

For dynamic programming you want an edge condition(s) and a way to score where you are right now. After that it's more-or-less smart brute force. The smart part comes from memoizing so you don't repeat work.

Here's a basic recursive approach for python that does the following:

- Organize table of cheese as a frozen set of tuples. This can be hashed for memoization and you can determine of a location is in the set in constant time.
- Creates an edge condition for the end (when both coordinates are N) and an edge condition for when you walk off the map -- that just returns 0.
- Uses `lru_cache` to memoize. You can implement this yourself easily.

---

```
from functools import lru_cache

def hasCheese(table, location):
    ''' Helper function just to improve readability '''
    return 1 if location in table else 0

@lru_cache()
def maxC(table, N, location = (0, 0)):  

    # edge conditions final square and off the grid:  
    if location[0] == N and location[1] == N:
        return hasCheese(table, location)
    if any(l > N for l in location):
        return 0

    # recursion
    score_here = hasCheese(table, location)
    return max(score_here + maxC(table, N, (location[0] + 1, location[1])),
               score_here + maxC(table, N, (location[0], location[1] + 1))
              )

t = frozenset([(2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5), (5, 2)])
N = 5

print(maxC(t, N))
# prints 3
```

If you want to do this in a top-down manner using a matrix, you need to be very careful that you always have the previous index set. It's easier to make mistakes doing it this way because you need to get the indexes and order just right. When you set it up as two nested increasing loops, that means the next value is always the current cell plus the max of the two cells one unit less — you should always be looking backward in the matrix. It's not clear what you are trying to do when you are looking forward with this:

```
 dp[i][j] = table[i][j + 1]
```

because `j+1` has not been determined yet.

Since the cheese coordinates are 1 indexed, an easy way forward is to make your matrix zero indexed and N+1 in size. Then when you start your for loops at `1` you can always look and at lower index without undershooting the matrix and avoid a lot of the `if/else` logic. For example:

```
def hasCheese(table, location):
    ''' Helper function just to improve readability '''
    return 1 if location in table else 0

def maxAverageOfPath(table, N): 
    # matrix is sized one unit bigger
    dp = [[0 for i in range(N+1)] for j in range(N+1)] 

    # iterate 1-5 inclusive
    for i in range(1, N+1): 
        for j in range(1, N+1):
            # because the zeroth row and column are already zero, this works without undershooting the table
            dp[i][j] = hasCheese(table, (i, j)) + max(dp[i][j-1], dp[i-1][j])
    # solution is in the corner
    return dp[N][N]

t = {(2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5), (5, 2)}
N  = 5

print(maxAverageOfPath(t, N)) #3
```

When you'r done your matrix will look like:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3]
[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Your starting point is at (1, 1) starting in the top-right and your answer is the bottom left corner.

Comment: I feel this answer dodges the question by ignoring OP's matrix formulation.

Comment: @Richard, the question is "how can I solve with python?" not "how to solve this with a matrix". They have tried a matrix solution and it gave them trouble. A recursive DP solution is easier to implement, easier to read, and less error prone. That makes it a fine answer for "how can I solve with python" and certainly not worth a down vote.

Comment: @Richard the word, "matrix," seems to be referenced only three times on this page, all in the two comments above this one. What are you talking about?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Richard is referring to the `dp` in the original post. It's a matrix that keeps track of the values as you proceed forward through the iterations. It's the other way of solving a dynamic programming problem.

Comment: So what? Op hasn't said anything about "staying true" to such an approach.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkMeyer: this is a really solid answer.

Answer (score 2):

At each point you have two options to move further :

1. array [row] [col+1]
2. array [row+1] [col]

As we have to find out a path which involves max cheese.
It can be achived by recurring through the array like below to solve the same:

Solution =>

```
array [i] [j] + Max(Recur(array [i] [j+1]), Recur(array [i+1] [j]));
```

Comment: `Max(array[i][j] + Recur(array[i][j+1]), array[i][j] + Recur(array[i+1][j]));` - seems to be more right